# XSLT: set name of transformed output file

Tags: java, apache-camel, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using Apache Camel `file` component and `xslt` component. I have a route where i pickup a xml message, transform using xslt and drop to a different folder.

Apache camel DSL route:

```
<route id="normal-route">
    <from uri="file:{{inputfilefolder}}?consumer.delay=5000" />
    <to uri="xslt:stylesheets/simpletransform.xsl  transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" />
    <to uri="file:{{outputfilefolder}}" />
</route>
```

I am mentioning Apache camel also here , to check if there is a way to set the output file name using Camel. I think, even without Camel, there would be a mechanism with pure XSLT.

I need to rename the transformed output file. But always i am getting the same input filename with the transformed content, in the output folder.

**eg: input file: `books.xml`
output file: `books.xml`**   [with the transformation applied]

**What i am looking for is *someotherfilename.xml* as the output filename. The output data is correct.**

I tried `<xsl:result-document href="{title}.xml">` , but then the output xml is blank. Please help.

**Input XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book.child.1>
        <title>Charithram</title>
        <author>P Sudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <book.child.2>
        <title>Java Concurrency</title>
        <author>Joshua Bloch</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

**XSLT:**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="yes" />
         <xsl:variable name="filename" select="'newfilename'" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.xml">
                <traders>
                    <xsl:for-each select="books/*">
                        <trade>
                            <title>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                            </title>
                        </trade>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </traders>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML when using `<xsl:result-document href=""` in XSLT**

*it is blank..*

**Output XML when not using `<xsl:result-document href=""` in XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<traders xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <trade>
      <title>Charithram</title>
   </trade>
   <trade>
      <title>Java Concurrency</title>
   </trade>
</traders>
```

Edit: edited the XSLT as per MartinHonnen's comment

Comment: Do you want to create a single result document or several ones? Your attempt with `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:result-document href="{title}.xml">` creates a file named `.xml` as there is no child element named `title` of the document node so `{title}` evaluates to the empty string.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen for pointing that, i have updated the code referencing a valid value. But anyway, that was not influencing the output filename. The output file name remains 'books.xml' before and after my change.  I want to create a single output document, which is the transformed XML

Comment: I think `<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.xml">` is fine in terms of XSLT 2.0, either you are not running Saxon or inside your environment result documents are handled differently. I have no idea about Apache Camel so I can't help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Camel's default is to use the same file name, but you can override it. As the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) mention you can specify the options of interest as follows:

```
file:directoryName[?options]
```

One such option is `fileName`:

> Use Expression such as File Language to dynamically set the filename.
>   For consumers, it's used as a filename filter. For producers, it's
>   used to evaluate the filename to write.

In short, modify your route as follows:

```
<route id="normal-route">
    <from uri="file:{{inputfilefolder}}?consumer.delay=5000" />
    <to uri="xslt:stylesheets/simpletransform.xsl  transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" />
    <to uri="file:{{outputfilefolder}}?fileName=foo.xml" />
</route>
```

Where `foo.xml` will be the output file.

**Update**

You can use [Simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) or [File](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html) language to set file names dynamically. There are a few examples in the links.

Comment: Well, this works, +1 for the details, and I will mark this as answer soon. I am trying to understand how to give a dynamic value to the filename. This value is obtained using xpath expression processing from the input file

Comment: I tried this , and it works, ` <to uri="file:{{outputfilefolder}}?fileName=$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd}.xml" />`    but i am looking on giving a name that is extracted using xpath.

Comment: The other way it worked for dynamic file name is to set the header with key as `CamelXsltFileName` and value as the filename, and passing `output=file` as the parameter to the `xslt:component` . I will update that as another answer

Comment: @spiderman were you able to dynamically set the output file name?